# how to delete/ignore a line from package.json as npm command

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, package.json

*This question is more related to webpack or node command.*

This may sound crazy but it is kind of requirement I have.

I've angular project which contains `package.json` with contains `different entries for different packages`.
like,

```
"dependencies": {
     ...
     ...
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"



    "myCustomPackage1":"file//../../some-relative-path",
    "myCustomPackage2":"file//../../some-relative-path"
  },
```

**FOR SOME REASON** I want to delete "myCustomePackage1" && myCustomPackage2" lines from package.json **(I DONT WANT TO UNINSTALL THE PACKAGEs)**.

Is there any why?

Usually I want to generate the build files for angular packages or in other words `npm package` for this angular project (not angular library).

Everything works fine even if I don't delete these two lines but when I use this generated package into other angular project, I get relative path error. So in order to avoid it, before I generate `npm package` for this project, I want to delete these two lines and then generate the package.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Just edit the package.json file,

Comment: Nope. I can't do it as whole build happens through `npm run build` which further contains so `many other commands`. So manually I can't do it but that it should be part of that `npm build` command

Comment: And Yes manually I can do it but then I have to build everything manually. I want to automate everything so asking if there is a way to do it.

Comment: just delete those lines using a script. Create a script to read package.json first, than run other build scripts in sequence.

Comment: How to do that? Any small example. Make sure files are in different directory.